# React setState mixing up objects

Tags: reactjs, state, onchange

My component shows a contact with firstname/lastname/etc held in an object

```
  getInitialState: function () {
    return ({
      contact: {},
      edit: false,
      editedContact: {}
    });
  },
```

After making ajax call, I store info in the state.contact and editedcontact

```
  success: function (payload) {
    that.setState({ contact: payload.result, editedContact: payload.result});
  }
```

I have a toggleEdit function to decide what I will render - either the contact view or inputs to edit the contact

```
  toggleEdit: function () {
    this.setState({
      edit: true,
    });
  },

   render: function () {
    if(!this.state.edit){
      var output = (
        <div>
          <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-heading">{this.state.contact.firstName</div>
            ...
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      output = (
        <span className="cancel" onClick={this.cancelEdit}>Cancel</span>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <input className="form-control" id="first-name" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "firstName")} value={this.state.editedContact.firstName}/>
            ...
```

The values of the form are already synced up with my editedContact for easier user experience and onChange, they updated the editedContact

```
  handleChange: function (paremeter, e) {
    console.log(this.state.contact.lastName);
    console.log(this.state.editedContact.lastName);
    var editedContact = this.state.editedContact;
    editedContact[paremeter] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({editedContact: editedContact});
  }
```

My cancelEdit changes the state of edit back to true to see the contact again, but I don't understand why I'm still seeing changes made to editContact in this view. My handleChange only updates the editedContact state, NOT the contact state, so why am I seeing changes made to the contact state through the console logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking it's due to a mutation bug. These lines in particular:

```
success: function (payload) {
    that.setState({ contact: payload.result, editedContact: payload.result});
}
```

What you are doing is setting each of those two keys to REFERENCE `payload.result`. Meaning, if you where to change `payload` then both `contact` and `editedContact` would be mutated. And you do just that when you do `var editedContact = this.state.editedContact` and then mutate the parameter.

To test whether this is happening or not, try cloning payload before setting it:

```
success: function (payload) {
    that.setState({ contact: {...payload.result}, editedContact: {...payload.result}});
}
```

Or without the spread operator:

```
success: function (payload) {
    that.setState({ 
        contact: Object.assign({}, payload.result), 
        editedContact: Object.assign({}, payload.result)
    });
}
```

Let us know if this works!

Comment: WOW!!! amazing!! thank you! I used your second suggestion, does that essentially do the same as the first by building out copies of payload.result?

Comment: Yeah it "assigns" all values in the second to `n` objects to the first object. So it mutates that first argument, in our case an empty, new object. The first one does the same thing but it's a JavaScript 2016 feature not yet released (you need to transpile with something like Babel, `stage-0` preset for it to work)

Comment: It's just "syntactic sugar" to make code leaner and more concise